# Java Android socket gets killed imidiatelly after screen goes blank

Tags: java, android, sockets

I use to connect with server a socket :

```
Socket requestSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(a, 6666), 3000);
```

It works pretty well all the time except when device stays in idle mode for longer time say 30 mins or so. After 30 mins if I bring device to wake state, and try to contact to server thro' my app it doesn't throw any exception. Which shows me that my socket connection is in still live state. But when I check at the server end same data is not received here.

Comment: please could you upload your exception log?

Comment: at where you write this connect code .  i think you written  inside onCreate only

Comment: @Tej I create a new Thread and on this thread I set connection

Comment: @redAllocator I don't ave an exception. When I have connect a device with pc all works good

Comment: @KrzysztofPokrywka your thread might be suspended , please check your thread is running or not in OnResume . if not then start again .

Comment: when do you connect for socket?

Comment: @Tej On thread |I have a task which I start all the time : https://paste.ofcode.org/vFWuRqamkHmrkhjN575iNN

Comment: @redAllocator on Thread I do this : https://paste.ofcode.org/vFWuRqamkHmrkhjN575iNN

Comment: Where you are calling this method **connectTask3**

Comment: on Create I did this:

     thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new connectTask3().execute();
            }
        };
        thread.start();

Comment: @Tej on Create I did this :      thread = new Thread() {
            Override
            public void run() {
                new connectTask3().execute();
            }
        };
        thread.start();

Comment: i might not sure . but once  try with calling this method inside onResume also .

Comment: @Tej but I want to work when a screen is lock

Answer (score 1):

Battery way is use background service with startForground

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    onHandleIntent(intent);
    return START_STICKY;
}


protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null) {
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getBaseContext())
                .setContentTitle("")
                .setContentText("Your content text");
        startForeground(1, builder.build());
        Socket requestSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(a, 6666), 3000);
    }

}
```

This service will never pause/closed your socket connection even your app is closed or removed from the recent app.

You can use Bind service from UI if you want to update UI from background service

```
@Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        if (TweetCollectorService.class.getName().equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Bound by intent " + intent);
            return apiEndpoint;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok But when this service is killed ?

Comment: its upto you when you want to kill it. you can kill it using stopSelf() function

Comment: so when I close app the service is stopped ?

Comment: No if you not kill it

Comment: so how I can killed this serivice ?

Comment: call stopSelf() in service

Comment: becouse when I killed app and open an application and onCreate I start a service I will have two service

Comment: first check service is running or not if yes then not start again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155902/discussion-between-krzysztof-pokrywka-and-rajesh-nasit).

Comment: How I can check if service is running  ?